# Django DurationField format options

Tags: python, django, sqlite, model

Good evening. I have a question do you have some snippet for DurationField to show it in django admin in format HH:MM? I can't find anything over the internet and 3rd party apps doesn't work in new django. Thank you for help.

Model:

```
from django.db import models



# Create your models here.

class Aircraft (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    #hours to maintenance
    hours_to_maintenance = models.DateTimeField(help_text = "test", null = True)
    #current hours
    ch = models.TimeField(help_text = "test", null = True)
    #rm = models.IntegerField(help_text = "test", null = True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration
```

Comment: any clues how to do that?